# Centering Fancyhdr leftmark and right mark

Tags: fancyhdr

I would like to know how it was possible to *center* the chapters and sections  marks (I don't know if they call it that) with this (MWE) code

```
 \documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}

 \usepackage{lipsum}

 \usepackage{fancyhdr}

 \fancyhf{}

 \fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}

  \fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}

  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}

  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}

  \renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\scshape#1}{}} 

  \renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\scshape #1}}

\begin{document}


 \chapter{chapter} % Even page header
 \lipsum[1]
 \section{section} % odd page header
  \lipsum[1-5]


  \end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\fancyhead[CE]{ ... }` and `\fancyhead[CO]{ ... }`.

Comment: I don't undestand what you mean, perhaps that the argument of \fancyhead = empty? I tried: nothing happened.

Comment: The dots represent the arguments of `\fancyhead` Ijust say to replace the optional arguments `[RE]` and `[LO]` with `[CE]`and `[CO]` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code. You had forgotten to declare the page style as ‘fancy’:

```
 \documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}

 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}

 \fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}
  \fancyhead[CO]{\rightmark}
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}

  \renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\scshape#1}{}}

  \renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\scshape #1}}
  \pagestyle{fancy}

    \begin{document}

     \chapter{A First Chapter} % Even page header
     \lipsum
     \section{A section} % odd page header
      \lipsum[1-10]

  \end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: If you want to have only the titles in the headers, it is easier with `titleps`:

```
 \documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}

 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{titleps}


  \newpagestyle{mine}[\scshape]{%
  \sethead[\thepage][\chaptertitle][]{}{\sectiontitle}{\thepage}
   }
   \pagestyle{mine}
    \begin{document}

     \chapter{A First Chapter} % Even page header
     \lipsum
     \section{A section} % odd page header
      \lipsum[1-10]

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great!!! Thank you! Would you mind telling me how it's possible, starting with this code, to remove the "Chapter #" (= only the actual chapter title) and "Section #" (= only the actual section title)?

Comment: Not even the section or chapter numbers?

Comment: yes please. I would be grateful!

Comment: It will be simpler to do with `titleps` (a companion package of `titlesec`) in the place of `fancyhdr`.

Comment: You're welcome! Beware that `fancyhdr` and `titleps` are incompatible since they tackle the same things.